# To solve given expression in R and find T value?

Tags: r, expression, equation

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YP6dy.png)I have an question concerning the possibility to solve functions in R, but to know the answer would really help to understand the R better.

0.10 = (1/(1+(((1.04e+19*((T/300)^(3/2)))/(4e+16))*exp((-(0.045)/(0.0259*(T/300)))))))

How can I solve this expression in R and find the value of T?

Answer (score 1):

Your equation does not have solutions. To see this define the function, defined over the positive reals,

```
f <- function(T) (1/(1+(((1.04e+19*((T/300)^(3/2)))/(4e+16))*exp((-(-0.045)/(0.0259*(T/300)))))))
```

and define a function `f(x) - a`, in order to solve the equation `f(x) - a = 0`.

```
g <- function(x, a) f(x) - a
```

Now plot this second function.

```
curve(g(x, 0.10), 0, 1e3)
```

[image]

As the graph shows, all values of `g(x, 0.10) = f(x) - 0.10` are positive, `f(x) != 0.10` for all `x`.
Analytically, if the functions never changes sign it does not have roots. Since the function is continuous, all we need to do is to check its value near `0` and the maximum.

```
g(.Machine$double.eps, 0.10)
#[1] -0.1
```

The maximum is determined with `optimise`.

```
optimise(g, c(0, 1e3), a = 0.10, maximum = TRUE)
#$maximum
#[1] 347.4904
#
#$objective
#[1] -0.09931205
```

Both values are negative, which confirms what the graph had shown.

---

## Edit

Everything that was said above is right but apparently the function's expression was wrong. With the correct expression the root can be found with `uniroot`. Note that the solution given in the question's image was found by trial and error, the solution below was found by a numeric method but they are the same solution.

```
f <- function(T) {
  numer <- 1.04e19*(T/300)^(3/2) / 4e16
  numer <- numer * exp(-0.045/(0.0259*T/300))
  numer <- 1 + numer
  1/numer
}
g <- function(x, a) f(x) - a

xzero <- uniroot(g, a = 0.10, interval = c(0, 1e3))
xzero
#$root
#[1] 192.9487
#
#$f.root
#[1] -1.149569e-10
#
#$iter
#[1] 13
#
#$init.it
#[1] NA
#
#$estim.prec
#[1] 6.103516e-05

curve(g(x, 0.10), 0, 1e3)
abline(h = 0)
points(xzero$root, 0, col = "blue", pch = 16)
```

[image]

Comment: The T value given in textbook is193

Comment: @SaurabhAgrawal That means you have posted the wrong expression. I had to edit it to add missing multiply signs. Check the function's expression.

Comment: wait i will be posting actual image of a problem

Comment: i have uploaded an image of problem plz click on enter image description here and check it @RuiBarradas

Comment: i have uploaded an image of problem plz click on enter image description here and check it

Comment: So we cannot get T value as 193 in code? @Rui Baradass

Comment: I was said to find solution using optim function @RuiBarradas

Comment: @SaurabhAgrawal I had a small bug in the code, now the solution is the solution in the book. As for `optim`, that's a function to find minima, not roots.

Comment: Thank you so much bro i got an solution @Rui Barradas